# Are there any userspace programs to interpret btrfs snapshot diffs?

Tags: filesystems, backup

I am currently looking into backups and want to speed up the process while staying file-based (as opposed to filesystem-based).
I want to use duplicity as the main backup component.
The idea would be to use the features of the underlying filesystem to narrow down the files that duplicity has to scan to determine the differences from the last backup.

I know that btrfs can make quick diffs between snapshots so that is what I want to use for now but I cannot seem to find userspace tools to actually handle the diffs that btrfs produces.

**Are there any libraries to interpret btrfs snapshot diffs?**

Obviously I am not going to hack the kernel with my nonexistand C skills, so the further away from the bare metal I am the more comfortable I am. Python would be great for example...
Or am I the only one who would like to quickly have a simple list of the changed files in  file system?

For reference: [a more complete desciption of my idea](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2142201)

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSuSE tool 'snapper' appears to show diffs between btrfs snapshots: http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Snapper